# overwrite resharper "Import symbol completion" plugin behavior

Tags: plugins, import, resharper, symbols, overwrite

When a new type gets referenced in code, resharper provides an option to "reference the dll and import the usings"

The dll reference added in csproj file, normally comes with the version and publickey information.
But i want to overwrite this behavior and have the reference to dll as follows: 
    
      False
      False
    
This does not include any version or key information.

Currently after the resharper adds the reference, we have to manually edit the csproj file and do the changes.

Please let me know if i can overwrite this behavior .

Comment: Reference to be as follows in csproj file
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>